# Numpy Array fill empty data to "uniformity"

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array with lack of data, and I want to fill them by giving a mathematical uniformity to the array. I got something like this :

```
[[72829],
 [nan],
 [73196],
 [73087],
 [nan],
 [nan],
 [72294.5]]
```

I want to fill those empy cells with the mean between the closest cells, with return with something like this :

```
[[72829],
 [73012.5],
 [73196],
 [73087],
 [72888.875],
 [72492.625],
 [72294.5]]
```

I tried to use [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer) and [KNNImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer) from Scikit-learn, but all what I got is the same value to all data, not the mean between the cells as I mentioned before. Thats the code :

```py
for label, column in data.iteritems():
            reshaped = np.array(column.values)  # Creating a np array to use scikitlearn
            reshaped = reshaped.reshape(-1,1)  # changing shape of data to a 2D array
            normalized = imputer.fit_transform(reshaped) # transforming data
            data[label] = normalized # changing the column value to the new one
```

With KNNImputer, I got something like this (The way that I don't want):

```
[[72829],
 [68088.71106114],
 [73196],
 [73087],
 [68088.71106114],
 [68088.71106114],
 [72294.5]]
```

Someone knows any ideia or algorithm that could give a "uniformity" to the array numbers like this ? The ideia is that the return of this method gives me the possibility to plot graphs without missing data. If were something with pandas/numpy/scikit-learn would be better, thanks.

Comment: You can use pandas, (bfill + ffill) / 2

Answer (score 0):

Convert data to a dataframe and use `b(efore)fill` and `f(orward)fill`

```
x = [[72829],
 [np.nan],
 [73196],
 [73087],
 [np.nan],
 [np.nan],
 [72294.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df = (df[0].bfill() + df[0].ffill())/2
df
>>>
0    72829.00
1    73012.50
2    73196.00
3    73087.00
4    72690.75
5    72690.75
6    72294.50
```

Comment: or rather `interpolate` if using `pandas`

Comment: I learned something new today :)

Comment: I did something like this, but the problem is that this kind of fill gives to all empty cells the same value, not  with a uniformity between them to make this "uniformity"

Answer (score 0):

```py
In[0]:
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series([72829,
 None,
 73196,
 73087,
 None,
 None,
 72294.5])

series.interpolate(method='linear')

Out[0]:
0    72829.000000
1    73012.500000
2    73196.000000
3    73087.000000
4    72822.833333
5    72558.666667
6    72294.500000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: That looks like perfect to me ! Helped me a lot !